# PHP Booking System - Inserting records after confliction check

Tags: php, sql, insert

I'm currently attempting a mock-up booking system and am struggling to get the records to insert correctly

Here's the function that is called when the "Book" button is pressed:

```
function bookAppointment($clientName, $aptDate, $aptTime, $aptDetails, $withWho) {
global $db;

//Ensure there are no conflictions
$confSQL = "SELECT aptDate,aptTime,withWho FROM appointments";
$confQuery = mysqli_query($db, $confSQL);

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($confQuery)) {
    if($row[0] == $aptDate) {
        if($row[1] == $aptTime) {
            if($row[2] == $withWho) {
                header("Location: dashboard.php?error=booking_confliction");
            } else {
                addAppointment($clientName, $aptDate, $aptTime, $aptDetails, $withWho);
            }
        } else {
            addAppointment($clientName, $aptDate, $aptTime, $aptDetails, $withWho); //Using another function makes repeated code considerably tidier
        }
    } else {
        addAppointment($clientName, $aptDate, $aptTime, $aptDetails, $withWho);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the 'addAppointment' function:

```
function addAppointment($clientName, $aptDate, $aptTime, $aptDetails, $withWho) { //Makes error checking easier
global $db;

$sql = "INSERT INTO appointments VALUES $clientName,$aptDate,$aptTime,$aptDetails,$withWho";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if($result) {
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
} else {
    header("Location: dashboard.php?error=sql_error");
}
}
```

The problem being is that nothing is added at all but I'm pretty sure the if statements check out fine, unless I'm just being blind. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Problem solved with an SQL statement change;

```
"INSERT INTO appointments`(clientName, aptDate, aptTime, aptDetails, withWho) VALUES ('$clientName','$aptDate','$aptTime','$aptDetails', (SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userId='$withWho'))"
```

Comment: Add try catch blocks.Also,function in function..this is a job for classes.

Comment: I got it - after many, many attempts I have changed my SQL statement to look like this `"INSERT INTO `appointments`(`clientName`, `aptDate`, `aptTime`, `aptDetails`, `withWho`) VALUES ('$clientName','$aptDate','$aptTime','$aptDetails', (SELECT `userId` FROM `users` WHERE `userId`='$withWho'))"`

Comment: If you have resolved your issue, please answer your own question.

Comment: I can't answer my own questions as I'm a new user - have to wait 8 hours first so I've edited the question to include the answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved with an SQL statement change;

```
"INSERT INTO appointments`(clientName, aptDate, aptTime, aptDetails, withWho) VALUES ('$clientName','$aptDate','$aptTime','$aptDetails', (SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userId='$withWho'))"
```